# Strictly concave function has a unique maximizer

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

It's a well known result that strictly concave functions have a unique maximizer. This allows us to take first order conditions to obtain that maximum.

But if I think about something like log(x), it is strictly concave, but clearly does not have a maximizer.

How does this gel with the first statement? How am I thinking about this wrong? Why does existance of a maximizer follow from strict concavity?

Comment: As you clearly show, it doesn't.  Uniqueness if it exists is all you have.

Comment: Ok. So what we are saying is - if there is an x which satisfies the first order condition being zero, then this x must be the unique maximizer. Is that correct

Comment: I don't know *exactly* what "the first order condition being zero" means, but if that has a precise meaning then probably yes.  If there is a local max then it is the unique global max (on the interval where the function is defined).  If there exist $x<y<z$ with $f(x)<f(y)>f(z)$, then by continuity there is a local max in the open interval $(x,z)$, and by strict convexity it is unique.

Comment: Given a strictly concave function $f$, one typically imposes that $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. This and strict concavity imply existence and uniqueness.